# nodejs actionhero download picture file trouble

Tags: node.js, actionhero

I'm building simple image file upload/download server and I'm following this [wiki page](http://actionherojs.com/wiki/core/file-server.html#sending-files-from-actions)
.  In this part I'm passing the xpath parameter which is the file name and it all works fine for text files but I'm getting 404 when trying the same for images.

```
  renderFile: function(api, connection, next){
    // do any pre-rendering etc here
    connection.rawConnection.responseHttpCode = 200;
    connection.sendFile(connection.params.xpath);
    next(connection, false);
  },

  run: function(api, connection, next){
    var self = this;
    if(connection.params.xpath == null){
      self.render404(api, connection, next);
    }else {
      var file = api.config.general.paths.public + '/' + connection.params.xpath
      console.log(file);
      fs.exists(file, function(found){
        if(found){
          self.renderFile(api, connection, next);
        }else {
          self.render404(api, connection, next);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

is there any settings or config I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems OK to me.  In a blank actionhero project, I can use the action below, and requests like `http://localhost:8080/api/file?xpath=logo/actionhero.png` work as expected

```
var fs = require('fs');

exports.action = {
  name:                   'file',
  description:            'file',
  blockedConnectionTypes: [],
  outputExample:          {},
  matchExtensionMimeType: false,
  version:                1.0,
  toDocument:             true,

  inputs: {
    required: [],
    optional: ['xpath'],
  },

  render404: function(api, connection, next){
    connection.rawConnection.responseHttpCode = 404;
    connection.sendFile('404.html');
    next(connection, false);
  },

  renderFile: function(api, connection, next){
    connection.rawConnection.responseHttpCode = 200;
    connection.sendFile(connection.params.xpath);
    next(connection, false);
  },

  run: function(api, connection, next){
    var self = this;
    if(connection.params.xpath == null){
      self.render404(api, connection, next);
    }else {
      fs.exists(file, function(found){
        if(found){
          self.renderFile(api, connection, next);
        }else {
          self.render404(api, connection, next);
        }
      });
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I already figured it out. I had a small mistake on client side and wasn't reading the stream properly.

Comment: @Evan: Hi, I created a `actionhero` tag, please subscribe to it, I know that you are the creator and I think it is an awesome API, which should get more traction on stackoverflow.